# python: accessing element in list of lists by single object

Tags: python, arrays, list

In Python, one can access an element in a 2dim numpy-array via:

```
matrix = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
indices = 1, 1
matrix[indices]
```

in this case, we can store the position of an element in the matrix within a single variable (here indices). Is there a similar thing available for a list of lists? In other word: If we cant use numpy, is there a better way than

```
matrix = [[1,2],[3,4]]
indices = 1, 1
matrix[indices[0]][indices[1]] # this line is ugly, isnt it?
```

Comment: I don't think you can do much better. Maybe unpack the data first: `row, col = 1, 1; matrix[row][col]`. Or use a loop over `indices`, although that wouldn't be nice at all.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to your second example, you could use:

```
matrix = [[1,2],[3,4]]
fst_pos, snd_pos = 1, 1
matrix[fst_pos][snd_pos]

>>4
```

This way you're avoiding using the indexing of your index variable(removes unnecessary use of brackets)